# Filter list of files according vector (import specificied png)

Tags: r

So I have a list of characters which contains names of png's I want to import. It is on the form:

```
names =  c("791365", "731823CK", "791652", "74164", "194817MKZ", "EK791073")
```

The names differ in both size and setup. These are the names of the png's I want to load. In the folder I'm loading from there are 1000's of png's but I only want to load the ones that have the names in my vector of names. 
I have loaded the paths for all the PNG's but strugge to filter so that only the names in my vector are loaded.

```
imgs <- list.files(path =".../Desktop/PNGs", pattern = ".png", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

I think a way of doing this could be lapply, but I am not sure. 
Is there a smart way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, or at least examples of names. To be specific my names it a character [1:459] and each entry is like "791365". Hope this clarifies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command extracts files from `imgs` that contain string from `names` in their file name.

First we use `basename` to remove path to file (we don't want to `grep` that). Next we get rid off `.png` extension. Then we search for `names` in our modified file names and extract original `imgs` string.

```
imgs[grep(paste0("^", names, ".png$", collapse="|"), basename(imgs))]
```

Comment: This works almost as I want it to. But the names have to match exactly in my case i.e. from "791365" I only want "791365.png" and not "791365_V2.png" as it looks like I am getting now.

Comment: Doing this gives me character(0) as output.

Comment: @Slangers Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Filter()` function.

```
Filter(function(x) grepl(x, imgs), names)
```

Comment: This won't work if `x` contains path to files (ie, `"791652"` from `x` is in path: `/home/user/791652/files.png`)

Comment: Yes, but it looks like the files he is filtering from all come from the same repo so it shouldnt be an issue here